# Make a post request to a remote service using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, django-models

I want to post the modal data (modal fields for each entry in JSON format) from my app (made up of Python Django) to a remote service using the provided endpoint URL.

I want to achieve something like this below of which I tried but failed

```
def modal_data_view(generics.ListAPIView):
    remote_service_response= requests.post(remote_url, data=my_modal_data)
    return HttpResponse(remote_service_response.text)
```

I am expecting my modal data to be received by the remote endpoint and return a text response.

Answer (score 1):

If your remote service supports REST api just do it with :

```
r = requests.post(remote_url,json=my_modal_data,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
```

also your "my_modal_data" must be in json format.
In REST api you may need authentication
there is an example of GET and POST to rest api  with token authentication in my github :

[Example of POST to REST](https://github.com/payamnaghdy/CarAssistRaspi/blob/master/uploader.py)

and if your remote does not use REST you may need to put your data in url (as options) or in body in the format of your remote service

Comment: I want to make the remote post and request calls using the Django Rest Framework (  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/  ). I want to take advantage of the framework ability to serialize and deserializing the modals and establish modal data exchange between my app and another remote app. I just still do not get it how i can achieve this.